# Function definition format

Tags: f#

Please consider as example a simple function that calculate the average between two numbers. It can be defined in both those ways:

```
let average = fun x y -> (x + y)/2

let average2 x y = (x + y)/2
```

Is there any kind of implication in those formats? Is it just a matter of style?

Comment: There are probably some very small differences, but the second would be much more common

Comment: The second is just more 'appealing' to read / deal with?